# How to use autocomplete with dropdown enabled in angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

I have a list of data that i have displayed in a dropdown. The html for drop down:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder=" oraganization " formControlName="organization">
      <mat-option>None</mat-option>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let org of orgList" [value]="org.id"> {{ org.name  }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

and the data in orglist is :
[image]
I have tried using ngAutoComplete, primeFace AutoComplete and Material AutoComplete too but i was not able to populate the data for those. Is there any other way or an actual way to use any of those AutoCompletes with Drop-Down.

Answer (score -1):

For the dropdown implementation, you can use **[angular material](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)**

Use the the [**autocomplete**](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) component for ui

Demo template

> **HTML**

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" (keyup)="updated()" [(ngModel)]="data">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Now to search with in an array of string (In this example `all[]`),
you can use this **logic**

Here I am using regex to match any substring of  those strings in the array

> **Typescript**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: string[] = [];
  data : any;
  constructor() {
  }

  public updated() {
    this.options = [];
    if (this.myControl.value.length > 0) {
      let all = ['John', 'Jenny', 'Jonson']
      let searchedWord = this.myControl.value
      for(let key in all) {
        let r = all[key].search(new RegExp(searchedWord, "i"));
        if (r != -1) {
          this.options.push(all[key])
        }
      }
    } else {
      this.options = []
    }
  }
}
```

Working example : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-material-search)